# D3 animation explaining base-10 notation

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, animation, d3.js

This is my first D3 code. I am self-taught so I am not sure that the chaining of the transition follows the common best practices. Also, is there a way to avoid duplicating the "group" and the "anim" while keeping the sliding effect I have  (cf `add 4 time the text "you choose  : abc"`)?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Input test</title>
 <div id="div1"> 

<form onSubmit="return false;">
  Choose a number less than 100.000: <input type="text" name="number" id="number"><br>

  </form>
  <svg width="900" height="300" id="pack1">
  </svg>

</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>

<script>
// get user number and start anim()
var inputElem = d3.select("#number");
inputElem.on("change", anim);

function anim() {
// remove previous animation
d3.selectAll("g").remove();

var number= d3.select(this).property("value");

if (number<100000){
    // general var
    var color = ["red","blue","orange", "green", "darkkhaki"]   



    //  get choices from user : number saved as array 
    var number_as_array = number.toString().split(''); 


    // add 4 time the text "you choose  : abc" 
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++){
    d3.select("svg").append('g')
        .attr('id', function(){return "group"+i})
        .append("text")
        .attr('x', 10)
        .attr('y', 30)
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "20px")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .html(function(){
                var text=["You choose :"]
                for (var index=0; index< number_as_array.length; index++){
                var x_position = (index+1)*30+100
                text.push("<tspan fill=\""+ color[index]+" \"y=\"30\"  x=\"" + x_position +"\" class=\"anim" + i+"\"  >" +number_as_array[index]+"</tspan>")
                        }
                return text.join(' ')
            })
    } 

    // start animation 
    d3.select("svg")
    .transition()
        .delay(1000)
        .duration(5000)
        .on("start", function anim1() { 
            // take abc and move them the line below before the =
            d3.selectAll(".anim1").transition().duration(2000)
                .attr("y", 60)
                .attr("x", function (d,i){
                        return 30+30*i
                })
            // take abc and move them the line below after the =
            d3.selectAll(".anim2").transition().duration(2000)
                .attr("y", 60)
                .attr("x", function (d,i){
                        return 50*number_as_array.length+100*i
                })

            d3.selectAll(".anim3").transition().duration(2000)
                .attr("y", 60)
                .attr("x", function (d,i){
                        return 50*number_as_array.length+100*i
                })

            // add "=" with opacity 0
            d3.select("#group1").append("text")
                .attr("id", "egal")
                .style("opacity", 0.0)
                .append("tspan")
                .attr("id", "egaltspan")
                .attr("y", 60)
                .attr("x", function(){
                return (50*number_as_array.length-30-30*(number_as_array.length+1))/2
                +30+30*number_as_array.length
                })
                .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                .attr("font-size", "20px")
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .text("=")
                .transition().duration(1000).on("start", function addtext() {

                    //change opacity of = to 1
                    d3.select("#egal").transition().delay(2000).duration(1000).style("opacity", 1.0)})

                    // change the abc on the right to a*100+b*10+c
                    d3.selectAll(".anim2").transition().delay(3000).duration(2000)
                        .text(function (d,i){
                            if (i <(number_as_array.length-1)){
                                return number_as_array[i] + "*" + 10**(number_as_array.length-i-1) +"    +"
                            } else {
                                return number_as_array[i] + "*" + 10**(number_as_array.length-i-1)
                            }
                        })


                    d3.selectAll(".anim3").transition().delay(3000).duration(2000)
                        .text(function (d,i){
                            if (i <(number_as_array.length-1)){
                                return number_as_array[i] + "*" + 10**(number_as_array.length-i-1) +"    +"
                            } else {
                                return number_as_array[i] + "*" + 10**(number_as_array.length-i-1)
                            }
                        })
        })  // end anim1

    // change the abc on the right to  a*10^2+b*10^1+c10^0
    .transition()
        .delay(0)
        .duration(2000)
        .on("start", function anim2() {
                d3.selectAll(".anim3").transition().delay(0).duration(1000)
                .attr("y", 90)
                .transition().delay(0).duration(1000)
                .text(function (d,i){
                    if (i <(number_as_array.length-1)){
                        return number_as_array[i] + "*10^" +(number_as_array.length-i-1)+ "    +"
                    } else {
                        return number_as_array[i]+"*10^"+(number_as_array.length-i-1)       
                    }
                })
        })

    // add circle
    .transition()
        .delay(0)
        .duration(1000)
        .on("start", function () {

        //add the circle : for each digits in the user's number  
        var g_width = 900/number_as_array.length
        var circle_size = g_width/30
        for (var index=0; index< number_as_array.length; index++){

            // create an array which length = digit
            var data = [];
            var length = number_as_array[index];

            for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                circle= {};
                circle.i = i;
                circle.cx = (circle_size*2*i+3)%g_width;
                circle.cy = (120*(circle_size*2*i+3))%g_width;
                data.push(circle);
            };

            // calculate the position of g representing that digit
            var g_position_x= g_width*index + 50

            //create  g for the digit
            var g = d3.select('svg')
                    .append('g')
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + g_position_x + "," + 120 + ")")
                    .attr("id", function(d){return number_as_array.length-index-1})

                // display the circle
                g.selectAll('circle')
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append('circle')
                    .attr('cx', function(d,i) { return d.cx; })
                    .attr('cy', function(d,i) { return d.cy; })
                    .attr('r', circle_size)
                    .attr('fill', color[index])
                    .attr('name', function(d,i) { return index+"-"+i; });           
            };    


        })  // end add circle   


}} // end if number <10000  + end anim()

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a pretty good code for a first attempt with D3. There are some considerations, though.

First of all, if you have an `if` condition testing the size of the input, it's a good idea writing the `else`. For instance:

```
else {
    d3.select("svg").append('g')
        .append("text")
        .attr("y", 50)
        .text("Number out of the range, please choose a new one.")
}
```

Now let's move to the big issues. The first one is this:

```
d3.selectAll("g").remove();
```

Any seasoned D3 developer will frown upon this. It's normally not a good practice removing elements to repainting them: you should **update** them instead. However, as this involves a really big refactor in your code, I'll leave this just as an advice.

The second issue that shows that your code is not an idiomatic D3 is the use of `for` loops to append elements. Like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    d3.select("svg").append('g')
    //etc...
```

Do not use `for` loops to append element. Use a data-binding approach instead, which is the idiomatic D3. So, the above code can be:

```
d3.select("svg").selectAll(null)
    .data(d3.range(4))
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    //etc...
```

Better than that, **name** your selections:

```
var groups = d3.select("svg").selectAll(null)
    .data(d3.range(4))
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    //etc...
```

For instance, instead of doing...

```
d3.select("svg")
```

... all the time, you can do:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg")
```

And simply use `svg` whenever you need. That's a good practice in a D3 code, so you can latter on refer to your selections without relying on classes or IDs.

Also, remove the `"You choose"` from the selection in the example above: you don't want to show it 4 times.

Finally, you're using the `start` listener of a transition selection to control other transitions. This is also not an idiomatic D3 approach, and things can quickly become complicated to control and understand. Instead of that, use a simple `d3.timeout`, or even a vanilla JS `setTimeout`:

```
d3.timeout(function(){
    //do your transitions here
}, 5000);
//   ^----- time in milliseconds
```

Here is your code with those changes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Input test</title>
<div id="div1">

  <form onSubmit="return false;">
    Choose a number less than 100.000: <input type="text" name="number" id="number"><br>

  </form>
  <svg width="900" height="300" id="pack1">
  </svg>

</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>

<script>
  // get user number and start anim()
  var inputElem = d3.select("#number");
  inputElem.on("change", anim);

  function anim() {
    // remove previous animation
    d3.selectAll("g").remove();

    var number = d3.select(this).property("value");

    if (number < 100000) {
      // general var
      var color = ["red", "blue", "orange", "green", "darkkhaki"]



      //  get choices from user : number saved as array 
      var number_as_array = number.toString().split('');

      d3.select("svg").append("g")
        .append("text")
        .text("You choose :")
        .attr('x', 10)
        .attr('y', 30)
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "20px")
        .attr("fill", "black");

      // add 4 time the text "you choose  : abc" 
      var groups = d3.select("svg").selectAll(null)
        .data(d3.range(4))
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('id', function(d) {
          return "group" + d
        })
        .append("text")
        .attr('x', 10)
        .attr('y', 30)
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "20px")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .html(function(d) {
          var text = [""]
          for (var index = 0; index < number_as_array.length; index++) {
            var x_position = (index + 1) * 30 + 100
            text.push("<tspan fill=\"" + color[index] + " \"y=\"30\"  x=\"" + x_position + "\" class=\"anim" + d + "\"  >" + number_as_array[index] + "</tspan>")
          }
          return text.join(' ')
        })

      // start animation 
      d3.timeout(function() {
        // take abc and move them the line below before the =
        d3.selectAll(".anim1").transition().duration(2000)
          .attr("y", 60)
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return 30 + 30 * i
          })
        // take abc and move them the line below after the =
        d3.selectAll(".anim2").transition().duration(2000)
          .attr("y", 60)
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return 50 * number_as_array.length + 100 * i
          })

        d3.selectAll(".anim3").transition().duration(2000)
          .attr("y", 60)
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return 50 * number_as_array.length + 100 * i
          })

        // add "=" with opacity 0
        d3.select("#group1").append("text")
          .attr("id", "egal")
          .style("opacity", 0.0)
          .append("tspan")
          .attr("id", "egaltspan")
          .attr("y", 60)
          .attr("x", function() {
            return (50 * number_as_array.length - 30 - 30 * (number_as_array.length + 1)) / 2 +
              30 + 30 * number_as_array.length
          })
          .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
          .attr("font-size", "20px")
          .attr("fill", "black")
          .text("=")
          .transition().duration(1000).on("start", function addtext() {

            //change opacity of = to 1
            d3.select("#egal").transition().delay(2000).duration(1000).style("opacity", 1.0)
          })

        // change the abc on the right to a*100+b*10+c
        d3.selectAll(".anim2").transition().delay(3000).duration(2000)
          .text(function(d, i) {
            if (i < (number_as_array.length - 1)) {
              return number_as_array[i] + "*" + 10 ** (number_as_array.length - i - 1) + "    +"
            } else {
              return number_as_array[i] + "*" + 10 ** (number_as_array.length - i - 1)
            }
          })


        d3.selectAll(".anim3").transition().delay(3000).duration(2000)
          .text(function(d, i) {
            if (i < (number_as_array.length - 1)) {
              return number_as_array[i] + "*" + 10 ** (number_as_array.length - i - 1) + "    +"
            } else {
              return number_as_array[i] + "*" + 10 ** (number_as_array.length - i - 1)
            }
          })
      }, 1000) // end anim1

      // change the abc on the right to  a*10^2+b*10^1+c10^0
      d3.timeout(function() {
        d3.selectAll(".anim3").transition().delay(0).duration(1000)
          .attr("y", 90)
          .transition().delay(0).duration(1000)
          .text(function(d, i) {
            if (i < (number_as_array.length - 1)) {
              return number_as_array[i] + "*10^" + (number_as_array.length - i - 1) + "    +"
            } else {
              return number_as_array[i] + "*10^" + (number_as_array.length - i - 1)
            }
          })
      }, 4000)

      // add circle
      d3.timeout(function() {

        //add the circle : for each digits in the user's number  
        var g_width = 900 / number_as_array.length
        var circle_size = g_width / 30
        for (var index = 0; index < number_as_array.length; index++) {

          // create an array which length = digit
          var data = [];
          var length = number_as_array[index];

          for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            circle = {};
            circle.i = i;
            circle.cx = (circle_size * 2 * i + 3) % g_width;
            circle.cy = (120 * (circle_size * 2 * i + 3)) % g_width;
            data.push(circle);
          };

          // calculate the position of g representing that digit
          var g_position_x = g_width * index + 50

          //create  g for the digit
          var g = d3.select('svg')
            .append('g')
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + g_position_x + "," + 120 + ")")
            .attr("id", function(d) {
              return number_as_array.length - index - 1
            })

          // display the circle
          g.selectAll('circle')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
              return d.cx;
            })
            .attr('cy', function(d, i) {
              return d.cy;
            })
            .attr('r', circle_size)
            .attr('fill', color[index])
            .attr('name', function(d, i) {
              return index + "-" + i;
            });
        };


      }, 6000) // end add circle   


    } else {
      d3.select("svg").append('g')
        .append("text")
        .attr("y", 50)
        .text("Number out of the range, please choose a new one.")
    }
  }

</script>
```

PS: It's worth mentioning that the math for your circles' positions has some problems.